# C programming error related text file input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen_s(file, "A.test", "r");
    fputs("Hello World!\n", file);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

here is my code. but i see a below error;;;;

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'file' used

how can i treat? what's problem?

Comment: You need to use `&file` as the first parameter, and you should check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28stdio%2Ffopen_s%29%3Bk%28fopen_s%29%3Bk%28DevLang-C%2B%2B%29%3Bk%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true) for what `fopen_s` returns.  It doesn't return a file pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to the file pointer, so that `f_opens` can set its value. Also, you overwrite the pointer with the return value, so that's going to be a problem. In addition you must open the file in write mode if you want to write to it, not read mode.

You should basically read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) better and also read about some basic concepts such as indirection.

```
FILE *file;
int err = fopen_s(&file, "A.test", "w");
if (err) {
    // handle error
}
fputs(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the signature of fopen_s.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    if (fopen_s(&file, "A.test", "r") != 0) {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fputs("Hello World!\n", file);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```